# how do I defer javascript execution until an asynchronous method completes execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, document-ready, .when

I have been looking into Jquery's `when` `then` and `deferred` keywords & functions but I couldn't get how do I apply them for a simple 3rd party asynchronous callback method in the `ready()` function of one of my views.

What actually happening is that my view gets `loaded` with no data because data was supposed to be populated from the completed execution of that asynchronous method in the `ready()`, but view is `loaded` before the asynchronous callback method could enter it's callback method. I have put an alert in that callback method and it never pops up as page has departed the scripts after loading completely.

Related to this, I have been looking into jQuery.holdReady() as well. I am kind of wandered as to how do I achieve synchronicity in this design.

This is how it looks like.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var xmlRequest = $('#requestStringHiddenField').val();
   var action = "getListOfReservations";
   asynchronousCallbackCall(xmlRequest, "callbackMethod", action);
}); 

function callbackMethod(result) {
     //unreachable      
     alert(result);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the second and third arguments to `asynchronousCallbackCall` are callback functions, you should pass the functions themselves, not their names as strings:

```
var action = getListOfReservations;
asynchronousCallbackCall(xmlRequest, callbackMethod, action);
```

Comment: The view ends up loading empty without waiting for the asynchronousCallbackCall to complete.

Comment: That's how asynchronous calls work. They return immediately, and the callbacks are called when it completes.

Comment: That is what I want to work against, by synchronizing this call in such a way that it pauses page ready() until the call completes and it reaches callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `$.ajax` for performing an asynchronous call, then you should use the attribute `async: false`, which will prevent the script execution until the call is finished and response is returned.

For more information on `$.ajax` please refere this link:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I am not using ajax. I am looking to synchronize an asynchronous JavaScript function in ready(), so that I can hold(pause) ready() to prevent the page from loading until the said function call completes.

Comment: Please provide the code of asynchronous JavaScript function !

Answer (score -1):

Use synchronous call instead of asynchronous. Synchronous request wait for the call to complete before it execute the next code.

> var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
>   request.open('GET', '/getListOfReservations', false);  // 'false' makes the request synchronous 
>   request.send(null); 
>   
>   if (request.status === 200) {
>    alert(request.responseText);
>   }

Comment: getListOfReservations is not actually some servlet action mapping but just a string parameter for the javascript method asynchronousCallbackCall(). Though I am not dealing with ajax exactly but I would like to know such an analogy for an asynchronous javascript function call also.

Comment: Eeeck - synchronous Ajax is the worst possible user experience.  It looks up the browser for the duration of the Ajax call.  It should pretty much never be used.